# View overlapping using library components

Tags: android, android-layout

I understand that View overlapping has been addressed for background images with components on top. However, what if I had the following, where the image from a button overlaps another view, outside of its container?

[Example 1](http://www.domandtom.com/mobile/example.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View are not allowed to overlapped in LinearLayouts. It is used to arange child views in either vertical or horizontal manner. When views are bigger than its parent, it renders in the bounds of its parent and the rest is cut of.

You can stack child views on top of each other by using the framelayout. But from seeing your buttun, I think you can achieve it using a Relative layout. And telling the arrow to stay below button using layout_below attribute.